# Scale to be considered for comparing electronegativities of nitrogen and chlorine

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, periodic-trends, electronegativity

The [Pauling scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity#Pauling_electronegativity) gives the $\chi$ values of $\ce{N}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ to be $3.04$ and $3.16,$ respectively, but the [Allen scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity#Allen_electronegativity) gives the $\chi$ values of $\ce{N}$ and $\ce{Cl}$ to be $3.066$ and $2.869,$ respectively.

Another point that should be made note of is that the most electronegative element as per Allen scale is $\ce{Ne}$. So, why is it accepted in the first place? And whose electronegativity is actually greater?

Comment: It is best to consider them equally electronegative if in different compounds but consider N more electronegative if in the same compound.

Comment: Is this just your opinion, or you can provide a reputable source or logical arguments to back up this claim?

Comment: Unanswered duplicate: [Which is more electronegative: chlorine or nitrogen?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/54006/which-is-more-electronegative-chlorine-or-nitrogen)

Comment: In [NCL3 - reactions and uses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_trichloride#Reactions_and_uses) is listed $\ce{NCl3 + 3 H2O -> NH3 + 3 HOCl}$ what gives a hint of higher N electronegativity, also mentioning moderate polarity.

Comment: @Poutnik But doesn't cite source and that would be plenty wacky too get such strong oxidiser and moderate reducer out of such reaction,,,

Comment: @Mithoron According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monochloramine, various reactions lead to both ways, so it is kind of electronegativity  deuce.

Comment: P.S.: NCl3 article cites 
Greenwood, Norman N.; Earnshaw, Alan (1997). Chemistry of the Elements (2nd ed.). Butterworth-Heinemann. ISBN 978-0-08-037941-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please take into account that there are a lot of different ways for calculating electronegativity.

1) Pauling obtains it by comparing the energies of dissociation of the three diatomic molecules AA, BB, and AB, stating that H electronegativity  is 2.1 !  Unit : √energy

2) For Mulliken, it is the average value between the electronic affinity and the first ionization energy of the atom. Unit : energy

3) For Allred - Rochow, it is the force acting between a valence electron and the charge of the atom when the other valence electrons are removed. Unit : force

4) For Sanderson, it is the average electronic density of an atom divided by the average electronic density of the corresponding atom of inert gas.No unit.